# Can we force WCF server bindings over client bindings

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

Here is the scenario,

We have IIS hosted web services on a application server, Now we have another application server where code is hosted and calls IIS hosted web services by creating channels and providing timeout bindings.

Now whatever we set in WCF server bindings for timeout value they always get overridden by Client bindings. **Is there any way we could force server bindings to be prioritized. Specially for timeouts**

Because we are using K2 Workflows which provides no way to add service references, we can't add service that way, we have to add it as a dll and then creating channels as you can see in code below,

Code:

```
 System.Net.NetworkCredential creds = GetCreadentials();
 HttpClientCredentialType credType = creds.httpClientCredentialType;
 BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
 binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
 binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = credType;
 EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(Url + "/_vti_bin/FruitFactory/Fruits.svc");
 ChannelFactory<Fruits.Internal.IFruits> factory = new ChannelFactory<Fruits.Internal.IFruits>(binding);
 factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = creds;
 factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = creds.UserName;
 factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = creds.Password;
 Fruits.Internal.IFruits proxy = factory.CreateChannel(endpoint);
 proxy.GetFruitCratesData(true);
```

**Edit**

I know how to use timeout bindings in client code, but that's what I don't want, I don't want my service to use clients bindings.

Answer (score -2):

You can force the client to use the settings of the server. But you can set the timeout in code

```
binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
```

Comment: That's what I don't want to happen, I don't want to give power to clients to add timeouts to there code.

Comment: You can't force the client to use a larger timeout than is configured at the client. The whole communication Always uses the shortest timeout.